# .htaccess redirect subfolder to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write a RewriteRule for my .htaccess file. Specifically, whenever a user accesses a specific subdirectory, I would like it to Rewrite to force an HTTPS connection.

For example, whenever someone accesses: `http://www.mydomain.com/subdirectory` (and any other sub-directories of that "subdirectory").

I'd like it to rewrite to `https://www.mydomain.com/subdirectory`

I've tried the following, but it appears to create a loop:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/subdirectory/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Also, this .htaccess file is placed in the root of my domain.

Any ideas on how to modify my RewriteRule?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would put this into the domain's root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(subdirectory/.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 21):

This work for me, this allow you to redirect to https a specific folder, just add an htaccess file inside of the folder with the following content:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I prefer this to the accepted answer as I don't need to specify the domain/subdirectories using this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Ahh, its a combo of the two.  MonoMano - you've omitted the subdirectory in the first part of the RewriteRule, therefore directing ALL traffic to the HTTPS subdomain address.  I found that checking for 'off' was more reliable than checking for !=on, dont ask me why!

You'd want to add the subdirectory back in as per Floern's response, see below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(subdirectory/.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/subdirectory/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the lines given below to .htaccess file of that subdirectory:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/subdirectory/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you don't want the address bar to show the subfolder. It will redirect `yourdomain.com` to `yourdomain.com/subfolder` but will look like you are still on `yourdomain.com`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yourprimarydomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yourmaindomain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subfolder/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: There are other answers that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some time ago. When posting an answer [see: How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove `www` prefix , and force `https`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^((?!subdirectory/).*)$ /subdirectory/$1 [L]
```

Change `example.com` for you main domain and `subdirectory` for Sub Directory

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/subdirectory/$1 [R=301,L]
```