# Redirecting ALL http traffic to https

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl, https

I've followed the advice from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762859/htaccess-redirect-subfolder-to-https) which redirects all requests for my case site, riverstreetflowerland.com to the https version.

You can click through to other pages on the site and view the site on https. However, if you get a direct link to a page other than the home page (like http://riverstreetflowerland.com/about-us/) then .htaccess will not redirect you to the https version and you will browse the site in http until you visit the home page.

Here's my current .htaccess as a reference:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I just need the site to be redirected to and browsed via https 100% of the time (it's funny how much a green padlock makes people feel secure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if you swap your rules this way

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: In your code, the redirection was never reached because of the first rule (WordPress' main rule to rewrite to the dispatcher/controller)