# Using htaccess to force specific directory to HTTP

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a Wordpress website and all my pages are HTTPS. Unfortunately, I have a couple script dependencies on a couple pages that require the page to be loaded over HTTP instead (otherwise it throws insecure content errors, etc.)

Luckily, all the pages I need to be served over HTTP, are under the same parent category:

```
www.domain.com/insecure/child-page
```

How would I force /insecure/ and all it's child pages/directories to be loaded over HTTP via htaccess??

Comment: if you leave out http, or use  relative links to these instead of the full URL, then it's solved...

eg leave out protocol  `<script src="//www.domain.com....`
OR use relative link `<script src="/insecure/js.js.`

Comment: Are those dependencies external sources that don't support ssl? if so you may be able to install a local copy and then you can link via any protocol you require.

Comment: They are, but it's a huge library, and closed source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the inverse of the example here [.htaccess redirect subfolder to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762859/htaccess-redirect-subfolder-to-https):

```sh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(insecure/.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Using this, I get an error for too many redirects. No other code in my htaccess file

Comment: Oops! Give it a shot now, I accidentally left the https on the example domain. Assuming you copied that, it was likely the cause.

Comment: I put in the edit, and the redirect isn't an issue anymore, but now it doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: There's no such variable `%{HTTP}`. You could say `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on` instead.